# Unity 3D - Sprite with the same physical size

Tags: unity-game-engine, size, screen, pixel, dpi

I'm trying to create an image with exactly 5cm x 8cm on any device. The problem is: the devices have different dots per inches (dpi) and this means that I need different pixel sizes to create the image. How can I calculate these different pixel sizes?

My approach:

1. Convert cms -> inches

   float widthInches = 5f / 2.54f;    // 1.9685f;

   float heightInches = 8f / 2.54f;    // 3.1496f
2. Find the size in pixels

   float realWidthSize = Screen.dpi * widthInches;

   float realHeightSize = Screen.dpi * heightInches;

I did these tests on my devices and the results were not as expected. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What were your results? Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: I was missing a thing! I needed to multiply the game width divided by the screen width. For example, my game width is 720p and the screen width is 1600, so I needed to multiply by 720/1600. It works but not in all devices.

Comment: @brunok8 how to get the game width and screen width?

Answer (score 0):

This may help! You can use this property to determine the DPI of the display!

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html

Comment: Oh Sorry, I forgot that you used that property in your code! However, see what Sceen.dpi is returning, it is possible that it cannot determine the DPI.